# How can I create a cross-tab of two columns in a dataframe in Python and generate a total row and column in the output?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, frequency, crosstab

I have created a dataframe from a CSV file and now I'm trying to create a cross-tab of two columns ("Personal_Status" and "Gender"). The output should look like this: [Crosstab of Gender and Personal Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkINf.png) including the frequencies of each gender/personal status combination and the totals of each generated row and column.

I tried `creditData[["Personal_Status", "Gender"]].value_counts()` but it's not quite where I want it. The output includes a column of each "Personal_Status" value, a "Gender" column, and the frequency of each combination, i.e row 1 = "Single, M, 232"

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at pandas .crosstab https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Kathy', 'Linda', 'Peter'],
                   'Gender': ['F','F','M'],
                   'Personal_Status':['Divorced','Married','Married']})

df2 = pd.crosstab(df.Personal_Status, df.Gender)

df2.loc['Grand Total']= df2.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=0)
df2.loc[:,'Grand Total'] = df2.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1)

print(df2)
```

**Output**

```py
Gender           F  M  Grand Total
Personal_Status                   
Divorced         1  0            1
Married          1  1            2
Grand Total      2  1            3
```

Comment: This didn't give me the expected output

Comment: hey, thanks! That gave me part of the output I'm looking for. Now I have to total the Divorced, Married columns and the F/M rows and display them

Comment: We're getting there! How's this latest update?

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends highly on current shape of your dataset.
You should group your data by their personal status and Gender and then summarize/aggregate count as you need the member of each category.
In this case if you have only status and gender try something like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Kathy', 'Linda', 'Peter'],
               'Gender': ['F','F','M'],
               'Personal_Status':['Divorced','Married','Married']})

df2 = df.groupby(by=['Personal_Status','Gender'],as_index=False).count()
df3 = df2.pivot(index='Personal_Status',columns='Gender')

df3
Gender             F    M
Personal_Status          
Divorced         1.0  NaN
Married          1.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dataframe is produced as:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Kathy', 'Linda', 'Peter'],
                   'Gender': ['F','F','M'],
                   'Personal_Status':['Divorced','Married','Married']})
```

This one liner will produce the requested output:

```py
pd.crosstab(df.Personal_Status, df.Gender, margins=True, margins_name='Grand Total')
```

**Output**

```py
Gender           F  M  Grand Total
Personal_Status                   
Divorced         1  0            1
Married          1  1            2
Grand Total      2  1            3
```

This is slightly simpler than the answer given by [@iamericfletcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66509591/1397843).